# Compare Static String and String from webview

Tags: ios, arduino

My App sends html to a Arduino with an Ethernet Shield. The Ethernet shield acts as a webserver and sends a simple message back to a UIWebview in the App. I'm using

```
NSString *myText = [myWebView2 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

If I ask NSLog to print my "myText" It prints out

```
<h2>Relay1 ON</h2>
```

Which is what is sent to the webview.  Now if I try to Compare myText with a static string that matches exactly, I get no result.

Heres the entire code block.

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)myWebView2;
{
NSString *myText = [myWebView2 
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
NSLog(@"my Text=%@",myText);
if ([myText isEqualToString:@"<h2>Relay1 ON</h2>"]) {
NSLog (@"If statement was triggered");
} 
}
```

If I look at the value of myText in NSLog it exactly matches yet the if statement is never triggered.
What am I missing in that if statement?
Thanks!!

Comment: this'l work fine if both are equal.

Comment: I think there are hidden characters that NSLog is taking care of for you.  Try adding this NSLog before your if statement.    NSLog(@"arduino length %d vs static length %d", myText.length, @"<h2>Relay1 ON</h2>".length); to shed some light on the issue

Comment: Hey thanks. You were right. ns log returned:2013-05-28 03:53:40.406 MicksRemote[64134:907] arduino length 21 vs static length 18. So I need to figure out what those 3 characters are and where they go or parse them out.

Answer (score 0):

Not Really Solved but I used NSRange to search myText for "Relay1 ON" and that works more efficiently than dealing with hidden Characters.  Thanks so Much for your help.